# Facial Recognition(not detection)using tensorflow lite(on device) in Android

Tags: android, tensorflow, face-recognition

Using Tensorflow lite I am trying to find a way for facial recognition (not detection) using camera given picture.

I googled everything related to this but all are detecting face.
I followed these links:

1. https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/android/detect-faces
2. https://medium.com/devnibbles/facial-recognition-with-android-1-4-5e043c264edc

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

https://medium.com/@tomdeore/facenet-on-mobile-cb6aebe38505 may be of interest to you. You'll likely need to find the corresponding TensorFlow model and convert it over instead of using an out of the box solution